# How to find key loggers or such kind of softwares in my computer?

Tags: windows, security, anti-virus, internet-security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

I usually try different kind of software which are available on net those can be trial versions or sharewares or freewares at the same time I use for online money transactions the same computer.Now I'm afraid if there are any key loggers or such kind of software in my computer. which I read somewhere is even antivirus software also cant identify such key loggers. Now I want to make it sure there are no such things in my computer. Is there any proper way to find out them and remove them?

Comment: Keyloggers are a subclass of spyware which is a subclass of malware. There's some basic things you should/could do: [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Comment: If you're willing to be promiscuous in terms of downloaded software, you take the chance of getting infected.  And there is no fool-proof way of avoiding infection.  Intelligent decisions and care are required.  If tools like MalwareBytes don't detect anything then you're PROBABLY ok... but the only certain way to know is to replace the computer (there are root kits that infect the BIOS so even wiping and/or replacing a hard drive may not be sufficient).

Comment: I think the real root of the issue is you're installing random crap on your computer. Get a Virtual machine to run crap on. If you suspect something is wrong, scrap the VM, get another copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

I use SanityCheck to scan for rootkits/malware on my laptop. The software performs a variety of scans to check for the aforementioned threat agents, and other irregularities which may indicate the present of malware/rootkits. The program also:

- Detects hidden/spoofed processes
- Hidden threads
- Hidden drivers
- Offers report at the end of the scan detailing reasons why irregularities indentified.

It's freeware and closed-source, but nonetheless I would strongly recommend it.